# I am using group_button package in flutter, * I have provided 7 buttons and i want to save the button data to a List<String> aminities

Tags: flutter, list, dart, button, togglebutton

- when user untap the tapped button the data is stored in the list again.
- if user select more than 3 button ,the button is not selected but the data of button is added in the list.
- I want the functionality such that only the selected button data is stored, please help me sort this, thanks

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:group_button/group_button.dart';
import 'package:tenants_community/listings.dart';
import 'package:tenants_community/new_listing/form_details_2.dart';

class DetailsForm2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DetailsForm2> createState() => _DetailsForm2State();
}

class _DetailsForm2State extends State<DetailsForm2> {
  List<String> aminities = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('hello sir ');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          GroupButton(
            enableDeselect: true,
            maxSelected: 4,
            buttons: [
              'Papaya',
              'Guava',
              'Pomegranate',
              'Orange',
              'Banana',
              'Cherry',
              'Apple',
            ],
            isRadio: false,
            onSelected: (index, i, isSelected) {
              if (isSelected = true) {
                aminities.add(index);
              } else {
                aminities.remove(index);
              }
            },
            options: GroupButtonOptions(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
              crossGroupAlignment: CrossGroupAlignment.center,
              mainGroupAlignment: MainGroupAlignment.start,
              unselectedBorderColor: Colors.grey,
              spacing: 7,
              buttonHeight: 30,
              buttonWidth: 80,
              selectedColor: Colors.grey[300],
              unselectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```